# module._init_() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) (scrapy tutorial w/ xpath)

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I'm not sure how I have 3 arguements here, and if so, how do i call DmozItem from items.py? This seems like a simple inheritance issue I'm missing. This code is copied directly from the scrapy tutorial website.

-- Shell error --

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS C:\Users\Steve\tutorial> scrapy crawl dmoz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('scrapy==1.0.3', 'console_scripts', 'scrapy')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.0.3-py2.7.egg\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 142, in execute
cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.0.3-py2.7.egg\scrapy\crawler.py", line 209, in __init__
super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.0.3-py2.7.egg\scrapy\crawler.py", line 115, in __init__
self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.0.3-py2.7.egg\scrapy\crawler.py", line 296, in _get_spider_loader
return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.0.3-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 30, in from_settings
return cls(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.0.3-py2.7.egg\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 21, in __init__
for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-1.0.3-py2.7.egg\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Steve\tutorial\tutorial\spiders\dmoz_spider.py", line 3, in <module>
from tutorial.items import DmozItem
  File "C:\Users\Steve\tutorial\tutorial\items.py", line 11, in <module>
class DmozItem(scrapy.item):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
module._init_() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

-- items.py -- my items list for parsing

```
import scrapy


class DmozItem(scrapy.item):

title = scrapy.Field()
link = scrapy.Field()
desc = scrapy.Field()
```

-- dmoz_spider.py -- this is the spider

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "dmoz"
allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
start_urls = [
    "https://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
    "https://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
]

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
        item = DmozItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistyped **scrapy.Item** class name.

In **`items.py`**, change:

```
scrapy.item
```

to

```
scrapy.Item
```

It should look like this:

```
import scrapy

class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()
```